# Move array in array to parent array php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a specific function to move array which is in array to the parent array as key or value.

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "id" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7)
"buydate" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "expire" } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) 
"planid" } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "buyer" } }
```

Result I would like to get is:

```
array() { [0] => 'id', [1] => 'buydate' etc. }
```

Or

```
array('id', 'buydate' etc.. )
```

Is it possible to achieve without foreach ?

Comment: any reason why you dont want foreach?

Comment: I prefer using functions instead of using foreach each time.

Comment: ... and what do you think that function is using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_map()` is extremely powerful and should do the trick:

```
$array = ... ; // your initial array
$flattened_array = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item[0];
}, $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to flatten the desired array, and use `foreach` you can do it this way.

Consider this example:

```
// Sample data:
$values = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 'id',
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => 'buydate',
    ),
    2 => array(
        0 => 'expire',
    ),
    3 => array(
        0 => 'planid',
    ),
    4 => array(
        0 => 'buyer',
    ),
);

$new_values = array();
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $new_values[] = $value[0];
}


print_r($new_values);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => buydate
    [2] => expire
    [3] => planid
    [4] => buyer
)
```

Or alternatively, you can you the `iterator`. Consider this example:

```
$new_values = array();
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($values));
foreach($iterator as $value) {
    $new_values[] = $value;
}
```

It should gave you the same output.